# How to change directory and run script for every file starts with same pattern like ICC.III.*

Tags: python, directory

How to change directory and run script for every file starts with same pattern like `ICC.III.*`

For example I have scripts with absolute path (in the same folder - this works only for 
one file)

```
with open('ICC.III.001.555.444','r') as f:
```

I want something like this -

```
with open('ICC.III.*','r') as f:
```

(For ALL file in the folder because the first part in name of the file is still same)

Where should I define this relative path and access to the folder?

Comment: do you want to execute the script or open the file? The code you posted does not execute scripts?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/glob.html1) module:

```
import glob

for filename in glob.glob('ICC.III.*'):
    with open(filename,'r') as f:     
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below:

```
 import os, fnmatch
 pattern = 'ICC.III.*'
 rootDir = 'C:\Users'
 for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(rootDir):
     for file in files:  #find all the files 
         if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, pattern): #check if the current file matching the pattern
             fullFilePath = os.path.join(path, file) #now do something with file
```

Assuming you want to go through the `rootDir` and for each file found in the directory and sub-directories, matching your pattern using `fnmatch`. Once the file name is matched, you can do your stuff.

Note: instead of `fnmatch`, you could use `startswith` also

Answer (score 0):

you can use pythons os.walk function to find your files in a directory tree

```
import subprocess
import os
def find_files(pattern,basefold):
    for root,dirs,files in os.walk(basefold):
        for fn in files:
            if pattern in fn:
                yield root, fn

for root, fn in find_files('ICC.III', basefold):
    os.chdir(root)
    cmd = "exec" # use your os specific execute command  here
    subprocess.Popen(cmd,Shell=True)
```